# regarding putting multiple patches for a single image into a single mini-batch

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, keras-layer

Regarding patch-wise training for image classification or segmentation, I need to put multiple patches corresponding to a single image into a single mini-batch during training process. How to do that in Keras? Or how can I ensure multiple training patches in a single mini-batch belong to the same training image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you implement your own generator for this. This doesn't need to be complicated. Your code will be something like this

```
class PatchGenerator():
    def __init__(self, batch_size, X, y):
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        # self.X is a list of input images
        self.X = X
        # self.y is a list of target classes
        self.y = y
        self.index = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        # Get next image
        image = self.X[self.index]
        target = self.Y[self.target]
        self.index += 1
        if self.index > len(self.X):
            self.index = 0

        batch = []
        for i in range(self.batch_size):
            # Generate a new random patch for the image
            patch = get_random_patch(image) # Implement this yourself
            batch.append((patch, target))
        return np.array(batch)

# Create the new generator
patch_generator = PathGenerator(32, X, y)

# Fit your model with the generator
model.fit_generator(patch_generator, samples_per_epoch=len(X))
```

The `PatchGenerator` class above will ensure that each batch only contains patches from the same input image. It will hopefully give you an idea of how you can implement this.

Take a look at the source code of `keras.preprocessing` for different functions you can use for generating the patches (https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/preprocessing/image.py).

Also, read this if you need to learn more about Python generators https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators.